# Specify which column not to load in numpy.loadtxt()

Tags: python

I'm using numpy.loadtxt() to open a csv file. My file has 33 columns and I don't want to load columns 16, 28, 23, and 25. I read that numpy.loadtxt has a parameter usecols where you can specify which column to load.

I think it is not neat to input numpy.loadtxt(usecols=0,1,2,3,4,5.... 15,17,... 33) in the code. Is there a way to handle my problem using numpy.loadtxt or there's another way to open a csv file so I can omit to open some columns in my file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a little set wrangling to produce the desired list of columns:

```
np.load(..., usecols=sorted(set(range(34))-{16,28,23,25}))
```

Comment: What  if you don't know the number of columns available in data?